# Winforms no puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'Microsoft.ReportDesigner, versión = 10.0.0.0' en VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, reportviewer

Tengo mi formulario que tiene ReportViewer (versión 10.0.0.0) y no me esta permitiendo abrir en VS2015

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que agregar las ***Microsoft Sql Data Tools*** desde el programa de instalación de Visual Studio.

Desde Programas y características > Visual Studio 2015 > Cambiar.

Comment: Ya lo tengo instalado

Comment: @ScottArielPerezQuispe tienes agregada la referencia a la dll? esta se copia al directorio de salida de tu compilado?